# On difference between overriding a function and hiding a function

Tags: c++

Is a function said to be overridden only if it is declared as `virtual` in base class and redefined in the derived class.
What do we call a non-virtual function which is has the same signature, but different definitions in the base and derived classes then?
A C++ beginner. thank you

Comment: the answer is already in the title.

Comment: First question: Do you know how the [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) concept works?

Comment: Just don't shadow (hide) non-virtual functions in derived classes. And for virtual functions you can help yourself by following those guidelines :
[virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final). So do not reuse virtual keyword in derived classes but use override.

Comment: @tadman That's an implementation detail. C++ doesn't require it to be implemented that way. It is better to understand it at the abstraction level.

Comment: @PepijnKramer If you have a better reference, conceptually speaking, by all means. I'm just suggesting that since it's how it often works *in practice*.

Comment: And yes tadman yes in practice many compilers do use vtable's. 
This is how I would summarize it : "A call to a virtual function results in a call to the implementation of the most derived class.", Regardless of how it is implemented And yes I always try to seperate how from what ;)